# Production App Outage. "H20 - App boot timeout"

Tags: heroku

Our production app is facing a serious `Outage with H20 - App boot timeout` error logged.

Evidence strongly points to a heroku platform issue. We need some fast support.

Comment: I'd suggest [logging a ticket with heroku](https://help.heroku.com/), they tend to respond quickly to issues like this.

Comment: Heroku does not take support ticket anymore. It really was good once.

Comment: We are now back. 50 minutes outage

Comment: Heroku takes tickets, but the help site has become ... weird. You have to search for something first, then you get a link to open a ticket.

Answer (score 9):

Just encountered this. I'm not sure what caused it but "heroku ps:restart" seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

After several attempts "heroku ps:restart" solved this issue with few minutes of downtime. It didn't help when I tried 'heroku restart' alone.

Comment: Any news on that? It happen with us and restart the dynos fixed the problem. Our last deploy was a week ago and we didn't change nothing from the heroku side of the application.

Comment: Would love to know this as well... last push was several days ago and out of nowhere, getting this exact issue.

Answer (score 2):

Listening to 127.0.0.1 leads to the **code=H20 desc="App boot timeout"** problem for us. Changing the **listening address to 0.0.0.0** solves the problem.

Also, don't use your own port, but instead **use the environment variable PORT** , which is passed to your app environment variables by heroku. Otherwise, you'll also get this problem.

Here is our node code:

```
const { PORT=3000, LOCAL_ADDRESS='0.0.0.0' } = process.env
server.listen(PORT, LOCAL_ADDRESS, () => {
  const address = server.address();
  console.log('server listening at', address);
});
```

So, try to log your listening address and port and check them firstly.

Comment: If you're working in Python using Flask or Starlette, you'll have to similarly use the environment variable PORT using `port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8008)) ` (after importing os).

Answer (score 2):

My solution was **CHANGE THE PORT**, that is the general idea.

In my case, I used NODEJS:

```
const app = express();    
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000); // Process.env.PORT change automatically the port IF 3000 port is being used.
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => console.log(`Node server listening on port ${app.get('port')}!`));
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue - `heroku restart` and `heroku ps:restart` didn't help me.

I temporarily upgraded the dyno (forcing a new dyno to takeover). This resolved the issue.